# Fine tuning BERT with my own entities/labels

Tags: neural-network, transformer-model, bert-language-model

i would like to fine tune A BERT model with my own labels, like [COLOR, MATERIAL] and not the normal "NAME", "ORG".

I'm following this Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14rYdqGAXJhwVzslXT4XIwNFBwkmBWdVV

I prepared train.txt, eval.txt, test.txt like this:

```
-DOCSTART- -X- -X- O

blue B-COLOR
motorcicle B-CATEGORY
steel B-MATERIAL
etc.
```

But whene i execute this command

```
!python run_ner.py --data_dir=data/ --bert_model=bert-base-multilingual-cased --task_name=ner --output_dir=out_ner --max_seq_length=128 --do_train --num_train_epochs 5 --do_eval --warmup_proportion=0.1
```

i get this error

```
06/08/2020 13:30:27 - INFO - pytorch_transformers.modeling_utils -   loading weights file https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-multilingual-cased-pytorch_model.bin from cache at /root/.cache/torch/pytorch_transformers/5b5b80054cd2c95a946a8e0ce0b93f56326dff9fbda6a6c3e02de3c91c918342.7131dcb754361639a7d5526985f880879c9bfd144b65a0bf50590bddb7de9059
06/08/2020 13:30:33 - INFO - pytorch_transformers.modeling_utils -   Weights of Ner not initialized from pretrained model: ['classifier.weight', 'classifier.bias']
06/08/2020 13:30:33 - INFO - pytorch_transformers.modeling_utils -   Weights from pretrained model not used in Ner: ['cls.predictions.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias', 'cls.predictions.decoder.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias']


File "run_ner.py", line 594, in
main()

File "run_ner.py", line 464, in main
train_examples, label_list, args.max_seq_length, tokenizer)

File "run_ner.py", line 210, in convert_examples_to_features
label_ids.append(label_map[labels[i]])

KeyError: 'B-COLOR'
```

Did i create wrongly train.txt file?

Answer (score 1):

add these label to the get_labels() metod in the run_ner.py file, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Did you change labels name in this file?

Comment: yes please change those